# Prime Faces: how to navigate from page A to (slow) page B with progress "Loading..." indicator

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2

I am using Prime Faces (JSF UI library).

I would like to navigate from page A to page B, but with some kind of progress indicator because page B is slow, it takes time to load.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with adding AJAX loading on page B. On page B you have something like this:

```
<h:head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function onLoadCallback(data) {
      if (data.status == "begin") {
        dialogWidget.show();
      } else {
        dialogWidget.hide();
      }
    }
  </script>
</h:head>
<h:body>
  <f:ajax event="load" listener="#{bean.onload}" onevent="onLoadCallback" render=":include1"/>

  <h:panelGroup id="include1">
    <h:panelGroup id="include2" rendered="#{bean.loaded}">
      <ui:include src="realPageB.xhtml"/>
    </h:panelGroup>
  </h:panelGroup>

  <p:dialogid="dialog" widgetVar="dialogWidget" modal="true">
    Loading
  </p:dialog>
</h:body>
```

With this you initially loaded just page with AJAX (it is fast), and you called method which updates panel which groups real page. During loading you will see modal dialog (you can experiment with `p:ajaxStatus` as well). In bean initali `loaded` is false, and after `onload` method is called you update `loaded` to true:

```
private loaded;

// getters and setters

public void onload(AjaxBehaviourEvent event) {
  loaded = true;
}
```

Comment: I am trying it, but doesn't work. What's `data` in `onLoadCallback(data)`?

Comment: For some reason it still doesn't work. `onLoadCallback` is never executed. ?

Comment: @Danijel In short, data is an object sent by ajax from JSF. You can use it to determine the life cycle of the ajax call(for instance whether the call succeeded or not)

Comment: @Danijel So basically this method will be called 3 times. When the ajax call begins, when it's complete and when it's successful. All he is doing is displaying a widget in the body as soon as the page is being loaded. When the call is invoked again, the widget will disappear.

Comment: Thanks. I still don't see why it doesn't call the method at all. Something is wrong, do you see what could it be?

Comment: Seems like there is a JSF bug: f:ajax can't be attached to h:body. Until this is resolved I have to search for another solution.